# CSS for comments

Tags: css

I am building a blog and for my comments I have this CSS.

```
#comments {
 position:absolute;
 border: 1px solid #900;
 border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #900;
 border-bottom: none;
 border-right-style:none;
 left:0px;
 top:352px;
 width:475px;
 height:183px;
}
```

However, after posting only one comment to test if it works, the text fills the `div` and moves out of bottom `div` limits. I want the div to expand as more comments come. How do I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you specify the height manually, the browser will not automatically resize it as the content grows.  If you wish, you may add an `overflow: scroll` directive to add scroll bars.  If you want the div itself to grow, remove the `height` directive, or replace it with `min-height`, although browser support for that is spotty.

Comment: The only browsers that don't support min-height are IE<8.

Answer (score 6):

Use `min-height: 183px` instead of `height: 183px`, so it can expand if needed.

Answer (score 3):

Remove your explicit height rule:

```
height: 183px;.
```

And the Div should now resize to fit comments.

You can use `min-height` to have it at 183px when there are no comments, but I am not sure if every browser treats this rule in the same way.

Answer (score 2):

Do not use `absolute` positioning for such kind of content. Remove `position` from this CSS.

Comment: I dont think you would need to replace it with something, just remove.

Answer (score 2):

Don't specify height.

If you must give it a basic minimum, use `min-height`.

Answer (score 2):

You may also want to set max-height to make sure it doesn't get too big.

Answer (score 1):

**Do not use absolute positioning for such kind of contents.**